# expandablelistview different styles for expand/collapse

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I am trying to get a custom Expandablelistview, that have different Layout for the states expand/collapse...

**Adapter**

```
@Override

public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

String headerTitle = ((User) getGroup(groupPosition)).getName();
if (convertView == null) {
    LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.con.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if(isExpanded) {
        Log.e("DBG", "isExpanded");
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.expanablelistview_header_expanded, parent, false);
    } else {
        Log.e("DBG", "isNotExpanded");
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.expanablelistview_header_collapse, parent, false);
    }
}

TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_user);
lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

return convertView;
}
```

**expanablelistview_header_collapse.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/transparent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/xml_border"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_user"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <View 
        android:background="@color/transparent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="10dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**expanablelistview_header_expanded.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/xml_border_top"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_user"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This was my try, but this methode is only called on start not on expand-state-change...

Thank you, for your ideas!

Comment: What layout do both layout contains?

Comment: rather changing layout you can hide and show your "view" and change background of your linear layout.

Comment: or put if-else condition outside if condition. it will work

Comment: @SurenderKumar thank you! But i will do really more changes but this ;)
Is it really the usefullst methode? And where outoside?

Answer (score 1):

The Problem was the

```
if (convertView == null)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Try loading the layouts in MainActivity in

```
<ExpandableListView Obj>.setOnGroupExpandListener();
```

and

```
<ExpandableListView Obj>.setOnGroupCollapseListener();
```